# Can I set up MAAS and Juju on one machine?

Tags: juju, maas, kvm-virtualization, virtualization, lxc

Here is what I want to setup:

- MaaS on a single PC
- MaaS providing the host OS for 4 VMs (3 LXC + 1 KVM)
- Using Juju to deploy services on the 4 VMs (nodes on MaaS)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

With this configuration You can do it:

1) Install MAAS on 1 VM

2) Add 3 VMs as node to MAAS

3) Install Juju on one of nodes

4) You have 2 node available for install Charm

5) you can define the machine number for deploying charms by adding --to 'Machine Number' to your command.

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

check this out ... hope this step by step guide helps you out ....
you can add nodes as described in the link ...

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2013/11/19/maas-and-juju-in-a-vm-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-part-2/

or this one

http://www.teale.de/tealeg/computing/cloud/kvm_maas_juju_openstack.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.